# Strange bug in a utf-8 windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, unicode, utf-8

Code (the .bat file is saved as utf-8 encoding)

```
chcp 65001>nul
echo 【123】
echo 【123】
pause
```

Obviously, the expected result is two line of `【123】`

But the actual result is

```
C:\Notepad++>echo 【123】
【123】

C:\Notepad++>【123】
'【123】' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Notepad++>pause
```

Why?

p.s. my windows language is chinese, if this related

Screenshot of demo and font settings of cmd.exe
[image: screenshot of the demo]

Comment: Batch files were never designed to handle Utf-8, expect things to break.

Comment: @Byzod Are you suggesting that the 2nd `echo` is getting skipped?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know what just happend

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Update your question to include a screen shot of the _Command Prompt_ window after running the .bat file, and the name of the font you are using. (I am using Julia Mono font.)

Comment: @skomisa I added it, looks like a normal font